# Dynamic rowspan column in primeng p-table

Tags: angular, html-table, angular6, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I want dynamic rowspan column in primeng p-table
https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/colgroup

I have tried this:

```
 <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <th *ngFor="let col of businessLogicMasterObject.columnList" [colSpan]="col.colSpan" [rowSpan]="col.rowSpan">
                    <div class="break-string-length">
                      {{col?.header}}
                    </div>
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <ng-template ngFor let-col [ngForOf]="businessLogicMasterObject.columnList">
                    <th *ngFor="let subheader of col?.subheaders" [colSpan]="subheader.colSpan" [rowSpan]="subheader.rowSpan">
                      {{subheader?.header}}
                    </th>
                  </ng-template>
                </tr>
</ng-template>
```

But this allow me only 2 level of rowspan:

[image]

How can I have another level of header?

Means As an image shows the header - Stock, subheader - SA, MA, A, U.
So the SA has also subheaders

Comment: What do you mean by multiple rowspan?

Comment: I did this thing before. Can you put your existing code on https://stackblitz.com/ with static data